# When I add Realm then it locks CFRunLoopRun and my queue for NSURLConnection

Tags: ios, realm, nsurlconnection

-app has serial queue for running NSURLConnection

-app is subscribed to connectionDidFinishLoading event

-app makes simple 'ping' to site and runs CFRunLoopRun in queue to enable events

-app closes connection after receiving connectionDidFinishLoading event,
    on CFRunLoopRun exit we log it and after exit from queue's task yet another task will receive slot for execution

-but if we add Realm then CFRunLoopRun will run indefinitely and now our queue is locked

I opened ticket https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/4737 also

```
#import "Realm/Realm.h"

@interface ViewController () <NSURLConnectionDataDelegate>
@end

@implementation ViewController {
  dispatch_queue_t my_queue;
  NSURLConnection *_connection;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  my_queue = dispatch_queue_create("my queue", NULL);

  dispatch_async(my_queue, ^{

    [RLMRealm defaultRealm];     // (1) // comment to make it running
    NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"]];
    _connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
    CFRunLoopRun();              // (2) infinite loop inside ios so (3) and (4) as result never been called
    NSLog(@"done");              // (3)

  });

}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
  dispatch_async(my_queue, ^{
    NSLog(@"test");              // (4) // never been called when realm is used in the same queue
  });
  _connection = nil;             // (5) // without (1) this line stops runloop so (2) and (3) will be called
}
```

Comment: Why do you expect the `CFRunLoopRun()` call to return? You're not calling `CFRunLoopStop()`, so the runloop will run until all sources have been removed. Assuming that nothing else uses the runloop is very fragile. I'd also recommend not running a runloop on any thread you don't own, particularly dispatch queues. There are a limited number of threads that service dispatch queues so doing anything that blocks them for an indeterminate amount of time, such as spinning a runloop waiting for network operations to complete, can lead to dispatch queues being starved, potentially causing deadlocks.

Answer (score 0):

`CFRunLoopRun` runs the runloop in the default mode until all sources and timers are removed, or `CFRunLoopStop` is called. Your code appears to be operating under the assumption that no-one else will ever add a runloop source or register a timer on that runloop, and that all runloop sources will be removed when your network request concludes. I don't think it's safe to make assumptions about the behavior of any third-party code you call into, whether it be Realm's or Apple's.

Furthermore, I'd advise against running a runloop on a dispatch queue. Dispatch queues a serviced by a limited number of system-owned threads, and it's frowned upon to block them for indeterminate amounts of time such as while waiting for a network request. `NSURLConnection` will happily let you [schedule the connection on a different runloop](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsurlconnection/1417485-scheduleinrunloop?language=objc), such as the main thread's runloop, or even [schedule delegate callbacks to happen on a dispatch queue](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsurlconnection/1411849-setdelegatequeue?language=objc).

If you *absolutely* must continue to run a runloop on a dispatch queue like this, you should use some explicit signal to determine when to stop running the runloop and then invoke `CFRunLoopStop`. I'd recommend avoiding this though.

Comment: I just want to understand what Realm does with current thread run loop. I check their docs and didn't find any mention about it in their docs about threading. I understand that run loop checks sources and timers but I don't sure Realm uses sources and I don't understand why they would want to use timers. But they have Realm mobile platform that is used for interconnection between client realm and remote + they send usage stats to their servers, probably that the issue, I don't know.

Comment: I just received that project and tried to add Realm to it for saving additional data and received lock in another place just by adding local database storage framework. Does GCD use pool of threads that pool dispatched queues?

Comment: And yes, now I need to call CFRunLoopStop in my network connection didFinishedConnection delegate's method just to stop current run loop and exit from CFRunLoopRun but it worked before and is not working now.

Comment: Realm uses a runloop source as a way of notifying threads about transactions being committed in a Realm. It drives the autorefresh mechanism mentioned in the section of the documentation on [seeing changes from other threads](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#seeing-changes-from-other-threads).